# Incorrect Output After Increment

Tags: c++, arrays, counter, output, increment

I'm trying to test the function showNumbers, however nothing is being printed out to the screen. I then tried to print out the value of an array index to make sure it has been incremented, but the value resulted in zero. Here is my input and output.

Input: 444a4
Output: 0

And here is a link to my header file: http://pastebin.com/PFeY3hpQ
And my main function: http://pastebin.com/5WLwNcy0

Comment: Two things.  One, that's WAY too much code to expect us to go through to find one error.  Narrow down where you think it would be and post that code.  Secondly, you gotta back down on the if statements.  I would strongly recommend looking into enumerations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not initialising *i* in the for loop in the `Counter::countnumbers` method. You have this:

```
for(unsigned int i;i<input.length();i++){
```

when it should be this:

```
for(unsigned int i = 0;i<input.length();i++){
```